# Use UINavigationBar appearance "back" icon for custom button?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I need to achieve a custom navigation bar's "< back" button as seen in the push segue, but on a modal.

[image]

I want to avoid too much hard-coding and found out about the property `UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage` and `UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage`.

I want to use these to put my own text beside them for my button, since using a .png doesn't look as natural as the real thing.

I tried this but the UIImage from those properties returns as `nil`.

```
func addBackButton() {
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    backButton.setImage(UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage, for: .normal)
    backButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    backButton.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitleColor(backButton.tintColor, for: .normal)
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage` is an optional value, therefore you won't be able to get the system default chevron from this. Rather, the system will use the image provided here if not null, otherwise revert to the system default.

If targeting iOS 13+, you can make use of Apple's SF Symbols, in particular the back button icon is referred to as `chevron.left`. To use this, call `UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")`. For earlier versions of iOS, you'll have to use an image set asset. You could target all versions of iOS using `if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { ... } else { ... }`, where you display the system image if on iOS 13+ for improved UI appearance.

```
func addBackButton() {
    let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left"), for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "backChevon"), for: .normal)
    }
    backButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    backButton.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
    backButton.setTitleColor(backButton.tintColor, for: .normal)
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite - I don't currently have a Back button so I need to replicate it programmatically. I'm not trying to replace the original because I don't have it in my view.

Comment: @JohnDoe Ah ok, sorry I misread the question. `UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage` is an optional value so I believe you won't be able to get the system default from that, rather only overwrite it such that if this isn't null then display the custom image, otherwise display system default. An alternative (if targeting iOS 13+) is to use Apple's SFSymbol Set, this would be `UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")`. If not then an image asset will be the only way, you could always use `#available(iOS 13.0, *)` to display the "better" back button for those users - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thank you, I would have never found that on my own.